# How to set the Dateformat for current date in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-format

I am developing one application. In that i write the below code for setting the `DateFormat` for current date. But it is working upto 9th month only. From 10th month onwards it gives the nil value. So please tell me how to solve this one. My code is as below:

```
 NSDate *datestr = clInfo.cldrinfodate;
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormat1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma"];
 NSString *date1 = [dateFormat1 stringFromDate:datestr];
```

Comment: can you tell datestr date means what you are getting from clInfo.cldrinfodate

Comment: That get the present date like 23-09-2011

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this one.

```
     NSDate * mCurrentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSLog(@"current date=%@",mCurrentDate);
    NSDateFormatter *dt=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSString *st=[dt stringFromDate:mCurrentDate];
```

Comment: -1 Simply changing the format string isn't an answer; it's shooting blindly from the hip with no idea what's actually going on.